# Unable to run any Jenkins pipeline after upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After updating some plugins related to the pipeline declarative model from v1.1.9 to v1.2 I'm unable even to run the simplest of pipelines, not to say that all my existing pipelines are not working.

A simple pipeline would be e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo 'hello world'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is always the same for all cases:

```
Started by user Roger
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git devops@code.careesma.net:chef-repo.git
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.function.Function
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1373)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2743)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1480)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:250)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:397)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:881)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:198)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onNewInstance(GroovyInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:195)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:200)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:21)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/Function
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2743)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1480)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:250)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:397)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:881)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:198)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onNewInstance(GroovyInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:195)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:200)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:54)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:96)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor551.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

There was a warning in the plugin page about running jobs, but nothing on breaking the syntax. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Model+Definition+Plugin

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like it requires java 8. Which java version do you use for running Jenkins?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko I'm running with java 7. I cannot see where this dependency is stated, though.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko just upgrated to openjdk-8 and I'm able to run the pipelines once again. Thanks! 

The java8 dependency looks like a mistake to me, as it was not required until jenkins 2.71, and the plugin only requires v2.7. Also in the plugin changelog there seem to be similar mistakes in the past. 

If you make the comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface was introduced in Java 8. So it tools like it requeries Java 8 to run. If you use any older version try to upgrade it.